# What would be the equivalent in bazaar of git bundle --all?

Tags: bazaar

When dealing with git repositories I use `git clone --mirror <URL>; git bundle create <file> --all` to create a backup clone of the repository in a single file. In there an equivalent way on **bazaar**?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to clone the branch, then run:

```
bzr bundle -r0..-1 .
```

inside of it.